# Connect to local mac server from device

Tags: ios, ruby, swift, xcode, sinatra

Im trying to connect to a ruby sinatra server that im running locally on my mac from an app using the following code:

```
func load(finished: @escaping ()->()) {

    // Create destination URL
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Images.zip")

    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: "http://waynerumble.local~waynerumble:4567/download")

    //Create Session
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in

        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {

                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {

                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

            finished()
        } else {

            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", (error?.localizedDescription)! as String);
            finished()
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

If i test the app from the simulator and set the `fileURL` to `"http://127.0.0.1:4567/download"` it works fine but from device i understand this has to be different so far I've tried:

From running ifconig in terminal i get `192.168.1.254` at en1 so i tried `"http://192.168.1.255:4567/download"` which gave me:

```
[] nw_socket_connect connectx failed: [13] Permission denied
Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@ Could not connect to the server.
```

Ive also tried:
 `"http://waynerumble.local:4567/download"` which gives:

```
Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@ Could not connect to the server.
```

`"http://waynerumble.local.~waynerumble:4567/download"`(waynerumble is my computer name and username) which gives:

`Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@ A server with the specified hostname could not be found.`

I also have wifi internet sharing on from both ethernet and iphone. Im not sure what else to try

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel or this https://ngrok.com/

Comment: ngrok will work, but you should be able to connect if both systems are on the same LAN.

Comment: both are on the same LAN, im sure im missing something but cant see why, would love to know as opposed to using ngrok which im installing atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`192.168.1.255` is a brodcast adress for your network and you should not use it.

Why dont you connect to your real IP `192.168.1.254`?

To bind Sinatra app to every interface try:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
```

Then `http://192.168.1.254:4567/download` should work.
Also remember about opening desired port in the firewall.

Comment: I did what you said, but couldn't find how to open up the port on my mac so i turned the firewall off completely and still got could not connect to server?

Comment: so i used `http://waynerumble.local:4567/download` and it worked. thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could help. http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-open-specific-ports-in-os-x-1010-firewall-3616405/ try it for opening ports. But disabling firewall just for tests should work.